# How can I see, which function has stuck?

Tags: debugging

This code runs infinitely. How can I see which function exactly had stuck and potentially fix the code?

```
f[x_] := 1/(x + 1)
g[x_] := 1/(x + 1)
prod1[x_] := 
 Evaluate[Refine[Integrate[f[x], x] Integrate[g[x], x], x > 0]]
prod2[x_] := 
 Evaluate[Refine[
   Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, x}] Integrate[g[x], {x, 0, x}], x > 0]]
prod2[x]
Inactivate[
    Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
      g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], Integrate] == 
   FullSimplify[
     prod1[0] + 
      Distribute[
       Integrate[
        ExpandAll[FullSimplify[D[prod2[x], x]]], {x, 
         0, \[Infinity]}]]] - 
    Limit[Sum[D[prod2[s x], x], {x, 1, Infinity}, 
       Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] // FullSimplify, s -> 0] // 
  ExpandAll // Quiet
Inactivate[
  Reg[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
     g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]], Integrate] == FullSimplify[prod1[0]]
```

Comment: The piece Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}] gives an error (that it does not converge). What do expect to happen to the larger expression? What does \[CenterDot] mean? Have you defined it?

Comment: @bills this is the whole code, no definitions besides. Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}] is not evaluated, obviously (see Inactivate), and if it was, it would not stuck anyway.

Comment: It appears you've got three expressions that are not within `Inactivate[]` statements:  `prod1[0]`; `Distribute[Integrate[ExpandAll[FullSimplify[D[prod2[x], x]]], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]]`; and `Limit[Sum[D[prod2[s x], x], {x, 1, Infinity},Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] // FullSimplify, s -> 0]`.  Since you want to know which function is sticking, did you try evaluating each of these individually? When I did, I got, for the 2nd one: `Integrate::idiv: Integral of (2 Log[1+x])/(1+x) does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}.`

Comment: @Anixx if you can answer the clarification questions that bill s has asked, it will help a lot to make more sense of this question you have asked. On the surface, it seems that there might be a problem with your misuse of an undefined `\[CenterDot]`. As for finding what takes the longest time or is running indefinitely in this code, you might find a value in making sure all of your sub functions work as you intend them to.